# Which String could give an UnsupportedEncodingException when using Base64 encoding

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, base64

Looking for a test case in which either the Base64 encode decode may break with an UnsupportedEncodingException or the decoded String will not be same as original. Intention is to create a set of test cases.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Encode {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        System.out.println(" Hellow Encode" );
        String[] test = {"+","+1"," !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_"
                ,"+name `~ name =="};
        try {
            for(String mes : test) {
                System.out.print(mes);
                String s=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(mes.getBytes("utf-8"));
                System.out.print("\t"+s);
                byte[] decoButes=Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
                String decoStr =  new String(decoButes, "utf-8");
                System.out.println(decoStr.equals(mes)); // If Falls Sucess
            }
        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            System.out.println("SUCESS"); // Wish if this is executed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try mocking a Base64 Encoder and have it throw an exception, and a Base 64 Decoder and have it return the wrong string.

Comment: @Compass that's a work around, but the code is somewhere as a lib and I am testing it.

Comment: If you can't edit the lib, then the library will be hard to unit test because Base64 is static.

Comment: See, I am passing String and taking its response. The code over here is to bring clarity to the ask. If you know a String, or some mechanism by which you could modify the code and prove that there is a case when the encoding may fail ,please help

Comment: The whole point of B64 is to be able to encode arbitrary binary data as plain old ascii. I can't imaging input that could not be encoded. Decoded is another issue, that should be easy to make fail as each 4 bytes of B64 encodes 3 bytes of data, there can be padding at the end of the encoded data represented as equals `=` at the end of the encoded string. Removing one of those `=` should make decoding fail.

Comment: I think you should use **UTF-8**: `String decoStr =  new String(decoButes, "UTF-8");`.

Comment: Replace each occurrence of `"utf-8"` with [StandardCharsets.UTF_8](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8), and you won’t have to catch UnsupportedEncodingException at all.

Answer (score 0):

No Base 64 encoded string can cause an *UnsupportedEncodingException* in your program. The exception is raised if the *charsetName* parameter of [String.getBytes(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)) or [String(byte[], String)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,java.lang.String)) is invalid. Since it is a constant in your program and the constant is a valid charset name, it will never be raised.

You can simplify your program by using other String methods:

Instead of:

```
mes.getBytes("utf-8")
```

Use:

```
mes.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

And instead of:

```
new String(decoButes, "utf-8")
```

Use:

```
new String(decoButes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

That way, the charset/encoding is checked at compile-time and the related exception handling code can and must be removed. Furthermore, there is no need to create a test case for it.